# Pre-increment in PHP with magic get and set defined

Tags: php, getter-setter, magic-methods, pre-increment

I have a problem that has been spoiling the way I want to do the things for a long time. It's related to the use of magic get and set in PHP and trying to do a pre-increment over an object. I have a PHP class like the following:

```
class Foo {
    public $object;

    function __construct() {
            $this->object = array("bar" => 1);
    }

    function & __get($name) {
            return $this->object[$name];
    }

    function __set($name, $value) {
            echo "Old value: ". $this->object[$name] ." - New value: ". $value ."\n";
            $this->object[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Note the `&` in the `__get` method. Now I run this code:

```
$o = new Foo();

echo "First test\n";
$o->bar = 2;

echo "Second test\n";
$o->bar = $o->bar + 1;

echo "Third test\n";
$o->bar += 1;

echo "Fourth test\n";
++$o->bar;
```

And the output is:

```
First test
Old value: 1 - New value: 2
Second test
Old value: 2 - New value: 3
Third test
Old value: 4 - New value: 4
Fourth test
Old value: 5 - New value: 5
```

The third and fourth tests have an unexpected (by me) behaviour. Looks like $this->object['bar'] returns the value to be set, instead the old value as I expected. How come the value is already set even before it's actually set?

If I remove the `&` from the `__get` method, this will work, so I guess it has something to do with the references management that PHP does. But I would expect the third test to behave the same way as the second, but it doesn't.

I really don't understand this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Haha, this is something we just bumped into and whilst it's confusing it's very interesting to see how php works underneath..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results are in fact (after careful consideration) what I would expect.

---

*First test*

Code: `$o->bar = 2;`
Output: `Old value: 1 - New value: 2`

The operations, in order:

- Assign a new value to `$bar` (call `__set()`)

Obviously this simply abandons the old value and puts a new value in its place. Nothing complicated.

---

*Second test*

Code: `$o->bar = $o->bar + 1;`
Output: `Old value: 2 - New value: 3`

The operations, in order:

- Get a *copy of* `$bar` (call `__get()`)
- Add one to it
- Assign a new value to `$bar` (call `__set()`)

The right side of the expression is evaluated, and the result is assigned to the left side. The value of the instance variable `$bar` is untouched during the evaluation of the right side, so you see it's old value at the beginning of the `__set()` call.

---

*Third test*

Code: `$o->bar += 1;`
Output: `Old value: 4 - New value: 4`

The operations, in order:

- Get a *reference to* `$bar` (call `__get()`)
- Add one to it
- Assign a new value to `$bar` (call `__set()`)

This is interesting - at first glance I'm a little surprised that you see the output generated by `__set()` with this operation. Because you are incrementing the value held in the original zval, not assigning a whole new value - and therefore a whole new zval - as you were with the first two, it seems that the `__set()` call is redundant.

However, when `__set()` is called the output that you do see is what you would expect, because the *referenced value* has been incremented *before* `__set()` was called. The value passed to `__set()` is the result of the increment operation, so it does not result in another one being added to it, it simply assigns the value of `$foo->bar` to `$foo->bar` - so you see the old and new values as being the same.

---

*Fourth test*

Code: `++$o->bar;`
Output: `Old value: 5 - New value: 5`

...semantically identical to the third test. The exact same operations in the exact same order resulting in the exact same output. Again, a little odd that there is any output at all, but there you go.

---

*Fifth test that I invented*

Code: `$o->bar++;`
Output: `Old value: 5 - New value: 6`

...semantically identical to the second test. This is again interesting and slightly unexpected, but it also makes sense, given that `$i++` returns the old value of `$i`.

---

At a guess the reason that `__set()` is being called unnecessarily in the third and fourth tests is:

- (unlikely but possible) because it would be more computationally expensive to work out whether `__get()` returned a reference or a copy than it is to simply call `__set()` - this seems unlikely since function calls are generally quite expensive.
- (more likely) because the `__set()` function can contain code that is nothing to do with the actual assignment operation, and it would be potentially seriously inconvenient if this code did not run when the value was altered. For example, if one was to implement some kind of event driven architecture that fired events when certain values were altered, it would be annoying if that only worked with straight assignments.

Comment: I always thought that the third test would be translated into something similar to the second. This behaviour gave me some serious headaches.

Comment: @Portnoy The solution is to get into the habit of always using `$var++` unless you need the new value as part of a larger operation - only then do you use `++$var`.

Comment: Yes, but the pre-increment must be supported in the system I'm working on. The real class where I'm having this problem stores in a different private attribute the changes made to the object, so that it pushes to the database only those fields that changed. With this behaviour, I can't tell if the new value is actually different to the previous one, so my approach for the moment is to update every field when the object is saved, as the pre-increments would make the condition fail.

Comment: You could implement some sort of diff functionality using the values as they are when they are returned by `__get()`? So in `__get()`, do `$this->diff[$varname] = $old`, then in `__set()` you can do `if ($old != $new || (isset($this->diff[$varname]) && $this->diff[$varname] != $new)) { // $varname has changed } unset($this->diff[$varname]);`

Comment: There's something I don't understand yet. If the only way I provide to change the `$object` attribute is via the `__set()` method, how could the `echo` be called **after** the value is set? I don't believe that PHP has a way to guess where I am going to put the new value, set it, and then call the `__set()` method.

Comment: @Portnoy It doesn't guess where you are going to put the new value, it is simply that you have incremented it **by reference** before `__set()` is called. When you do `$var += 1;` or `++$var;` the value of the zval associated with `$var` is incremented directly. When you do `$var = $var + 1;` a second zval is created to hold the result of the right side of the expression `$var + 1` and the value is migrated from one to the other. So with `++$var`, because it is incremented by reference, by the time `__set()` is called (redundantly) the value has already been altered. If you follow me. :-O

Comment: Thank you. After thinking a bit more, now I got it, sorry for my insistence, but I wanted to have it completely clear.